# Frame removed from DOM - is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get rid of my video playing in the background after closing the popup. Right now what I have is this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.slider-links .modalClick').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#overlay')
            .fadeIn()
            .find('#modal')
            .fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery('#modal .close').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#overlay')
            .fadeOut()
            .find('#modal')
            .remove();
    });
});
```

Using the remove method to get rid of the video that kept playing in the background, however, this is not exactly what I want since this way it doesn't allow to click on the link again, so my question is; Is there a better, more neat way, to do this? Feel kind of silly asking this but I don't really know what to look for when trying to find the answer at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you just stop the video

Comment: Because my visitors probably won't do that and expect it to stop after closing the popup.

Comment: what I mean is on close of the popup you can stop the video

Answer (score 1):

I'd stop the video and `fadeOut` the `#modal`.

```
jQuery('#modal .close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#overlay')
        .fadeOut()
        .find('#modal')
        .fadeOut();
    $('#overlay video')[0].pause();
});
```

Comment: I don't want to have to stop it manually, do you have an idea how I could do this on click/close?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to stop the video on close of the modal like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.slider-links .modalClick').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#overlay')
            .fadeIn()
            .find('#modal')
            .fadeIn();
        $('#overlay video')[0].play();
    });

    $('#modal .close').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#overlay')
            .fadeOut()
            .find('#modal')
            .fadeOut();
        $('#overlay video')[0].stop();
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks good, and I've tried that, but it still keeps on playing in the background after closing